# Find functions with specific arguments

Tags: r, function, arguments

How can you find the names and locations of all the functions that have a specific argument?  Is there a way to find them for functions in the global environment, attached packages, and installed packages?

Comment: @Arun: Yes, but it's tangential to the original question, so 1) it's unlikely anyone will find it by searching, and 2) it's likely that question will be deleted.

Comment: Any particular reason you're asking?  After all, the name of an argument to a function is pretty much arbitrary, e.g., the arguments `x` and `arg` in agstudy's excellent answer.  Some wiseacre like me, seeing your request, could go off and rewrite his packages so the argument `xlim,ylim` suddenly become `xlims,ylims` just to drive you crazy.  :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume that you ask the question just to not lose [Ben great answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426033/range-on-a-field-containing-nas/14426041#14426041)
Here I slightly modify Ben answer to search for any argument :

```
uses_arg <- function(x,arg) 
  is.function(fx <- get(x)) && 
  arg %in% names(formals(fx))
```

For example to get function with `na.rm` argument :

```
basevals <- ls(pos="package:base")      ## package name : here I use the base package
basevals[sapply(basevals,uses_arg,'na.rm')]
```

**EDIT**

better to `name` argument of `ls` in conjunction with  `asNamespace` :

```
basevals  <- ls(asNamespace('base'))
basevals[sapply(basevals,uses_arg,'na.rm')]
```

Comment: am a little confused by `## base and stats packages`, I don't see anything from `stats`, just `base`?