# See if a variable/function exists in a package?

Tags: r

I'm trying to test whether a particular variable or function exists in a package. For example, suppose I wanted to test whether a function called `plot` existed in package 'graphics'.

The following tests whether a function `plot` exists, but not what package it comes from:

```
exists('plot', mode='function')
```

Or I can test that something called `plot` exists in the `graphics` package, but this doesn't tell me whether it's a function:

```
'plot' %in% ls('package:graphics')
```

**Is there a nice way to ask "does an object called X exist in package Y of mode Z"?** (Essentially, can I restrict `exists` to a particular package?)

(Yes, I can combine the above two lines to first test that `plot` is in `graphics` and then ask for the mode of `plot`, but what if I had my own function `plot` masking `graphics::plot`? Could I then trust the output of `exists('plot', mode='function')`? )

Background: writing tests for a package of mine and want to test that various functions are exported. I'm using package `testthat` which executes tests in an environment where I can see all the internal functions of the package, and have been stung by `exists('myfunction', mode='function')` returning true, but I've actually forgotten to export `myfunction`. I want to test that various functions are *exported*.

Comment: This is in relation with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430728/find-functions-with-specific-arguments/14430885#14430885)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 environment(plot)
<environment: namespace:graphics>

find('+')
#[1] "package:base"

find('plot')
#[1] "package:graphics"

find('plot', mode="function")
#[1] "package:graphics"
```

Comment: Environment is a bit of red-herring here - that's the environment where `plot` was created, not where it's found.

Comment: I guess it would be a red herring in the case where a function is generic as it surely is here. If it were not generic then wouldn't that tell the user where any calls would first be searched for?

Comment: Notice that the environment of `plot` is `namespace:graphics` but it's found in `package:graphics` - those are different environments. There's more detail in https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/environments (search for function environments)

Comment: That should be very helpful. I see that your development of that resource is progressing nicely. In particular I have several times attempted to improve my ability to "compute on the language" but found the various resources ineffective in getting through to my mental models. I think your patient efforts to explain this might be more effective that the others I have consulted.

Comment: I'm finishing up the functional programming chapters and computing on the language is next on my list to expand and rewrite.

Answer (score 14):

Oh, I found it.

I noticed that in `?ls` it says that the first argument (`'package:graphics'` for me) also counts as an environment. `exists`' `where` argument has the same documentation as `ls`' `name` argument, so I guessed `'package:graphics'` might work there too:

```
exists('plot', where='package:graphics', mode='function')
[1] TRUE  # huzzah!
```

Comment: +1 but this don't work for internal function. **:::**, i.e `exists('parse_formula', where='package:reshape2', mode='function')`

Comment: `getFromNamespace('parse_formula',ns='reshape2')`

Comment: Yeah, I specifically don't want internal functions...oh, I see I said "exists" in my question, I meant "exports"! oops

Comment: @agstudy `exists('parse_formula', where=asNamespace('reshape2'), mode='function')`

Comment: @hadley ok:) ( I was pretty sure to see such comment) thanks!

Comment: It won't work for a package that isn't in `search()` either

Answer (score 0):

All the answers proposed previously walk environments, not namespaces. Their behavior will therefore differ depending on whether the target package was loaded with `library()`, and in what order.

Here is an approach with `utils::getFromNamespace()`:

```
function_exists <- function(package, funcname) {
    tryCatch({
        utils::getFromNamespace(funcname, package)
        TRUE
    }, error = function(...) { FALSE })
}
```